# Javascript function call to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

My Javascript function calling a sever side callback function.
This is working fine when I give alert(). If I comment alert() then the browser throw a warning ..

My function is

```
 function callMe(){   
  var input = 'input parameter list'; 
  var val=  <%=gridCtrlUsers.ClientID%>.callbackControl.Callback(input);    
   // If I comment this alert ,it would throw a browser warning.
   alert(val)  // This prints true or false
 }
```

Could anyone please help me ?

Comment: what is the warning? Can someone who is able please edit OP with code tag?

Comment: @Thomman, this doesn't look standard. Are you using a ComponentArt's  CallBack control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with José this doesnt look standard.

If its a custom control that has a client side API then have you tried just typing out its identifier rather than using the `<%  %>` tags...

You havnt mentioned what 3rd party toolkit your using but I know with DevExpress their components (such as the grid) have a property that allows you to set the client side instance name. You can get the grid to then call back from your client code by doing something like `gridClientName.PerformCallback()`.

If it is ComponentArt's grid you are using then I think you can set the grids client name with the `ClientObjectId` property and then use `gridClientName.callback()` in your Javascript.

If you just want to call an ASP.NET function from your Javascript code you could use an ASP.NET Script Manager AJAX control. I will give you an example below...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<script runat="server">

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static String Msg()
    {
        String userName = "Chalkey";

        return userName;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    PageMethods.Msg(OnSucceed);

    function OnSucceed(result)
    {
        alert(result);
    }
</script>
```

Hope some of this is useful! **:)**